# Which verbal tense is used in the sentence ビールを飲んで運転するのはダメだ。 for the verb nomu?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, tense

I'm trying to understand which verbal tense is used for the verb nomu in this sentence.

ビールを飲んで運転するのはダメだ。

According to http://www.japaneseverbconjugator.com/VerbDetails.asp?txtVerb=%E9%A3%B2%E3%82%80

all the verbal tenses used with "nonde" also have another word (such as iru, imasu, ita, etc. ) Which verbal tense is used here then and why the 飲んで is alone?

Comment: This is a typical usage of the basic て form of verbs. I suggest you read up on it and then come back if you still have questions.

Comment: I've read about it but it doesnt make sense with what I've read. It doesnt look like imperative form here and it doesnt have an "iru", "imasu","ita", etc to be a progressive form. And in all the articles I read they dont go further than that on the issue. Perhaps you can recommend an article at least in the commentary section with an example that fits that sentence if you dont want to bump the topic

Comment: https://kawakawalearningstudio.com/all/exactly-te-form-japanese/

Comment: "all the verbal tenses used with nonde also have another word".. No, the standalone te-form is so important and useful on its own that it's clearly listed in the third row of the table you linked.

Comment: @Pablo て isn't a tense, it's a conjunction.

Comment: @naruto well there is listed with another word even though I  suppose you can skip the kudasai or kure, that tense I assumed it isnt being used here because it's imperative and it doesnt make sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The te-form of verbs roughly means "and".

The things that you mention adding after the te-form, such as iru, are different verbs. nonde + iru means something like "drink AND be" (roughly corresponding to "(I) am here drinking" in English for this example).

The verb after the te-form does not always need to be iru or any of the others you listed. It can also be 運転する as in your question.